# What interval am I supposed to use?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I encountered a problem that I'm unsure how to solve.

Here is the problem:

Find the area between two successive intersections of $h(x)=\sin x$ and the curve defined by $h'(x)$.

So, I first got the derivative of $h(x)$, which is $\cos x$.

Then, I saw on the graph that $\sin(x)$ is above $\cos(x)$ in the interval $[\frac \pi4, \frac {5\pi}4]$.

I used that in the integral $$\int_\frac \pi4^\frac{5\pi}4 (\sin(x)-\cos(x))$$ and got $2 \sqrt2$

My problem is that it says successive intersections, so am I supposed to skip $\frac{5\pi}4$ for $\frac{9\pi}4$?

Comment: No, your first guess is right. Those are successive intersections.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ are continuous on $\mathbb R$ and have intersection points $\displaystyle\left\{(4k+1)\frac\pi4\middle|\, k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$

Thus, for each $k\in\mathbb Z,$ the area between $h$ and $h'$ is \begin{align}&\left|\int_{(4k+1)\frac\pi4}^{(4k+5)\frac\pi4}\sin x-\cos x\,\mathrm dx\right|\\=&\left|\left[\sin x+\cos x\right]_{(4k+1)\frac\pi4}^{(4k+5)\frac\pi4}\right|
\\=&\left|\sqrt2\sin\left((2k+3)\frac\pi2\right)-\sqrt2\sin\left((2k+1)\frac\pi2\right)\right|\\=&\left|2\sqrt2\cos((k+1)\pi)\sin\frac\pi2\right|\\=&2\sqrt2.\end{align}